# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Tags: angularjs, cors

I've seen several questions and answers around this and mine is half working.

I have a node.js api server with url api.domain.com and the website on an nginx server at www.domain.com when I do the following in angular the request goes through on the api server, I see the request I see it getting parsed and put into the database. However, on the client side I do not get a return right away and then eventually I will see `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I know what is causing this behavior but shouldn't it throw the error before it hits the API server? Also note that the node.js server has cors enabled. The response that should be coming back is json.

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "http://api.domain.com/addtrans/" + $scope.accountID,
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            transformRequest: function (obj) {
                var str = [];
                for (var p in obj)
                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                return str.join("&");
            },
            data: {
                payload: JSON.stringify(trans)
            }
        }).success(function (result) {
            $scope.trans = {};
            console.log(result);
        });
```

Comment: are you using express with node?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-*` are *response* headers, not request headers.

Comment: Yes I am using express.

Comment: It is throwing an error because the response returned from the express server doesn't allow CROS in the header. So it can't throw the error before the request hits the API server.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below middleware for all of our projects and it has been proven to work best.

```
const allowCors = (req, res, next) => {

    /** Allow all origins, for now TODO */
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, Content-Type');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');

    /** Browser check for pre-flight request to determine whether the server is webdav compatible */
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.sendStatus(204);
    }
    else next();
};

// Put this code before the routes you want to allow CORS to
app.use(allowCors);
```

You should change the Allow-Origin to something more restricted for security reasons.

The above code covers CORS as well as pre-flight on most browsers(this ia  major issue we were having in the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

i used this a while ago (express 3.x):

```
// npm install --save cors
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static());
app.get('*', function(){});
require('http').createServer(app).listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the cors header should be on the response which is coming from server not the request which is sent from client.

You can use a middleware to enable cors on the server:

```
//CORS middleware
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'example.com');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    next();
}

//...
app.configure(function() {
    ...
    app.use(allowCrossDomain);
    ...
});
```